# Meaning of the "On guard!" exclamation

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I recently watched the very epic ending of the Shrek 2, and when the cat draws his rapier, he shouts "On guard!" to the castle guardians.

I perfectly understand the meaning from the context, but was unable to find the exact usage situtaion in any of the dictionaries.

Is it the similar to "Defend yourself!", when a person wants an attack not to be by surprise, but a fair battle and gives their opponent a chance to ackwnowledge the attack?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You probably couldn't find it because you tried to spell it in English. It's a loan phrase from the French. As [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/en+garde) explains:

> **en garde**  (*interj.*)
>   Used to warn a fencer to assume the position preparatory to a match.
>   [French : *en*, on + *garde*, guard.]

Interestingly enough, ***on guard*** can [also be found in dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=on%20guard&ls=a), but it means something a little different. The very useful OneLook page also lists [entries for **en garde**](http://www.onelook.com/?w=en+garde&ls=a).

Comment: ^vote with a mystery: When I follow your link to onelook.com, it doesn't mention "on guard" anywhere. I tried some "customize" settings with no luck.

Comment: @lauir - The first link ([can also be found in dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=on%20guard&ls=a)) is the one that links to "on guard" on OneLook.

Comment: See also  http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/en%20garde

Comment: @hmmn - OneLook is a good site to get several dictionary links for one word. (This is often useful, because one dictionary seldom tells the "whole picture.") If you're looking for a single site that lists related words, try [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/on%20guard).

Answer (score 6):

From the [British Fencing Dictionary](http://www.britishfencing.com/about-fencing/glossary_of_terms/),

> **GUARDS**
>
> fencing positions - see prime, seconde, tierce, quarte, quinte, sixte, septime, octave

For instance, this gentleman from "[A New System of Sword Exercise for Infantry](http://www.ejmas.com/jnc/jncart_burtonnewsword_0200.htm)" is in the "prime guard".

[image: An infantryman in prime guard]

As J. R. mentions, the phrase is borrowed from French, and is occasionally said by fencers before they practice against each other. It means "get in position", with an implied "I'm about to hit you".

Comment: Okay, but you haven't at all discussed how the OP was mistaken that it was "on" rather than "en" or what that means.

Comment: I was told that it means "I'm ready to fight!"